# How to create Routing between Mobile Hotspot Network and USB tethered device?

Tags: networking, routing, home-networking, hotspot, tethering

I have two PC, One has only WiFi and other one has only ethernet port. I want to share data between them using local network. To do that i need one WiFi router with LAN port and one LAN Cable which i don't have. So i am trying to do with mobile phone. By Creating usb tethering in PC1 which has only ethernet port (No WiFi) and PC2 will be connected to the same phone using WiFi by creating hotspot in that phone, But both PC will get different Network ID so it can not communicate. What should i do to establish communication between both PCs

Edit: Both PC1 and PC2 are dual booting system. It has ubuntu and windows 10 on both so i can run any combinations of it.

Comment: Answerd depend on which OS is running in the PC1. Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I have updated the question